# How to debug a segmentation fault that occurs after the execution of a program

Tags: coredump

I run a program which terminates apparently correctly, but then a segmentation message appears:

```
./run_program
Start processing
Successfully finished.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How do I go about debugging the above ? I have run the program through a debugger and it gets to the last line and exits, then a segmentation fault message appears. If the segmentation fault occurred during the program I would have seen it during the debugging, so I am guessing it occurs at the moment the program is exiting, when some memory is liberated incorrectly or something like that. But I don't know how I can find out where that might be without some debugging.

Based on what I have seen elsewhere, it seems I need to look for the core dump. But I cannot find it. I am using a Red Hat 7 machine. I don't know where cores get dumped on that machine. Can anyone suggest where I should look ?

Comment: I'd guess it's not "after the execution of a program", it's after the last line of `main` in C++. Destructors and deallocations are still called. So, a classic UB like array out-of-bounds or whatever. I'd start with compiling with `-fsanitize=address` and fixing all UB found.

Comment: Did the debugger provide a stack trace? If it didn't, which I doubt, you can still see the trace. Sounds like a destructor is double freeing or something along those lines.

Comment: There will be no one who can help you with this, as you show zero code. You'll need to [edit] your question to fit the guidelines found in [ask] and [mre].

Comment: "then a segmentation fault message appears" At this point you start debugging as usual.

Comment: *If the segmentation fault occurred during the program* -- It *is* occurring during the program.  The ending `}` in `main` does not mean "the program is over".  As mentioned, there are objects that will need to have their destructor(s) invoked.  If you declared one of these objects, and the destruction process is buggy, then that is an error.  `int main() { SomeBuggyClass c; }` -- if `SomeBuggyClass` has bugs in the destruction, then you won't see it until after the `}` is invoked.

Comment: Review all the memory allocations in your program and verify there is an appropriate delete for each allocation.  If constructions allocate dynamic memory, verify that the destructors delete the memory.  Also, verify that the necessary destructors are declared as virtual.

Comment: This is one of the trickier of the many places you can shoot yourself in the face with globals. Object Y is instantiated after after global Object X and Y is used by X. At program exit, Y is destroyed first, X tries to use Y, and hopefully you get an Earth-shattering kaboom! so that you know you <expletive deleted>ed up and know to fix it rather than getting some sort of silent corruption that goes on to kill someone.

Comment: Thanks you for all your replies above. Indeed, the debugger was able to inspect the code following the exit from main (which I had not noticed before) and, as a result, I was able to see what was leading to the Segmentation fault. I haven't solved it yet (it only occurs occasionally) but your responses have set me on the trail.